# PHP - IF-statement false, still runs

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The last hour I've been sitting with this problem. I have two if-statements (for testing purposes they are both IF-statements, and not IF- and ELSE IF-statements. The code runs the false IF-statement as if it is true.
The code:

```
<?php
$sth = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM myDBTable WHERE alien1='$idkod' OR alien2='$idkod'");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
if(!$result)
{
    echo "No data";
}
else
{
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $alien1 = $row['alien1'];
        $alien2 = $row['alien2'];
        if($idkod == $alien1)
        {
            echo $idkod . "==" . $alien1;
        }
        if($idkod == $alien2)
        {
            echo $idkod . "==" . $alien2;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This will give me the following text on screen:
1234567891234567891234567==1234567891234567891234567
1234567891234567891234567==1234567891234567891234568

Clearly, the second text shouldn't be there, as the statement is not true.

Comment: As a first step, I'd try using ===.

Comment: Of what type is $idkod? It smells like some type casting magic. Did you try this with *much* smaller numbers or string values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't assume anything when making conditional forks, use var_dump() on the variables to temporarily look inside them - that way you best decide how to check for the exact type and value you are expecting.

Then as said already, prefer to check using ===

If you adopt this behaviour you will save countless hours and avoid some quite subtle bugs which can appear in your code.

Having the [PHP Truth Table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)s pinned up for a while will help.

Comment: I just var_dumped every variable, they're all string(25). I thank you for your answer, and I will be using === from here.

Comment: In fact, at the given link (PHP Truth tables) it shows a comment by "php at richardneill dot org" that explains this exact problem! +1

Answer (score 7):

`==` ignores type when testing for equality. In this case it will assume that both strings are numbers and convert them. This means this will turn into:

```
9223372036854775807 == 9223372036854775807 //Max int val. Will be different on different systems.
```

`===` will make sure that both arguments are the same type and will not attempt to coerce making

```
'1234567891234567891234567' === '1234567891234567891234568';
```

Give the expected result.

PHP equality is wacky sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

It is wrong to use `==` you need to use `===` the second is value comparison, the first is object comparison (depending on the context)

Comment: But the values are already not the same: `1234567891234567891234567 != 1234567891234567891234568`

Comment: Ha? I just said, and you ignored **==** is not the same as **===** it has a different meaning and handling inside PHP. Use **===**

Answer (score 0):

I  have modified your code a little check it

```
   <?php
$sth = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM myDBTable WHERE alien1='$idkod' OR alien2='$idkod'");
 $result = $sth->fetchAll();
if(!$result)
{
echo "No data";
}
  else
    {
   foreach($result as $row)
    {
      $alien1 = $row['alien1'];
      $alien2 = $row['alien2'];
     if($idkod == $alien1 && $idkod != $alien2)
     {
         echo $idkod . "==" . $alien1;
     }

      if($idkod == $alien2 && $idkod != $alien1)
      {
        echo $idkod . "==" . $alien2;
      }
   }
  }
 ?>
```